# .Net Core 2.0 multiple auth schemes - default scheme overrides all

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I have two authentication schemes that work fine alone. When I put the two together and define a default schema, the default schema overrides the schema that I set in my controller.

Here is my startup.cs:

```
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            //options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
        {
            options.Authority = Configuration["Authentication:Domain"];
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.ApiName = Configuration["Authentication:ApiName"];
            options.ApiSecret = Configuration["Authentication:ApiSecret"];
        })
        .AddIdentityServerAuthentication("AdminAuth", options =>
        {
            options.Authority = Configuration["AuthenticationAdmin:Domain"];
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.ApiName = "api_name";
        });
```

On my controller I'm setting the scheme:

```
[Route("myRoute")]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "AdminAuth")]
public class MyRouteController : ControllerBase
{
```

And on the other cotrollers I dont set the scheme:

```
[Route("myOtherRoute")]
[Authorize]
public class MyOtherRouteController : ControllerBase
{
```

If on statup.cs I define "options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme" to MyOtherRouteController works without the need to specify the AuthenticationSchemes, when I call "MyRouteController" controller, the app tries to authenticate throw the DefaultScheme.

What I'm doing worng? How can I configure a default scheme?